# What is the meaning of a "nodal official"?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

The local electricity linesmen, electricity inspectors, and other nodal officials in the electricity department also have key roles to play

Nodal means - of or relating to a node

Then what does "nodal official" mean?

Comment: Most likely it's supposed to mean something like *other types of officials* or *officials with different areas of responsibility*. The use of *node* is probably being used in the sense of *role*. Unless I'm mistaken, it's doubtful that English is the author's native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "nodal official" probably means the officials or engineers responsible for sections of the grid that are connected to or affected by any material change to any particular node.